# Is it possible to submit multiple records at once in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I need to figure out a way for a user to input around 150 data points collected easily and quickly. I have no experience with Access so I don't know if it is possible to do this, but I need a way for a user to input a table like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WAQs.png)

Preferably all in one form without going record by record.

Answer (score 1):

You layout is not really different then say a typical invoice, or say a purchase order in which “many” rows of data are attached to a given order, event or whatever.

So if you were entering data points for a given day, or test, then you would create a main table that outlines the details of the test (date, who did the test etc.). You then would build a table with the data points, and relate that table to the “test” event.

You then build a form, and drop in a sub form that displays the many rows in a table like format (you could even use a datasheet). The end result is a form in which they can enter data and simply hit tab to jump to the next column – when they are on the last column, the hitting tab would jump to the next row thus facilitation data entry with relative ease.

Here is a screen shot of “shift” work for a given employee, but the concept is the same for an invoice, an order, timesheet hours, or in your case a set of data points. The top part is "one" record that is the employee, and then the "many" rows are a sub form (a continues sub for in this example).

[image]